# Fetching data from firebase is null

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Code

```
    DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(UID);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData");

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsersHelper, UsersViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsersHelper model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
            holder.setImage(model.getImage());

            final String userId = getRef(position).getKey();


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData").child(userId);

                    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            userName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", userId);
                            intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", userName);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Currently the data showing is null because the data doesnt exist in the defined database reference(mDatabaseReference)

What I want to achieve is inside the "Friends" child and inside the 'userid' there will be multiple userids(friends ids) So i want to fetch all the friend ids take that... Go to "UserData" and fetch data of all the already fetched friends ids... Its bit of a complicated so i didnt know how to do... Can someone please help me out

Comment: No its not... but in friends there are unique ids... and those unique ids are a child of userdata... so i want to take those unique ids and go to userdata and fetch data in there @Mohsen

Comment: Oh now I see. Couldn't you add a seperate item that contains the UIDs in there so you get access to it by getting the child of `UserData`? `UserData -> orderByChild("uid")`

Comment: I could just fetch all the data in userdata but i want to fetch only the friends data so have to get a complicated code @Mohsen

Comment: For handling lookups on such indexed data, use FirebaseUI's `setIndexedQuery` method as shown here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data

Comment: If you want at some point to try **[Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)**, here you can find a tutorial on how to can create a [Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).